# TSP taking into account shapes of cities

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

I'm looking for a solution of symmetric Traveling Salesman Problem in which we take into account shapes of cities. For example, in the graph from geeksforgeeks.org, the shortest path is 1-2-4-3-1 [image: TSP sample graph]

We can imagine that cities aren't points but e.g. horizontal lines (because in a case of choose another shapes the problem will be much harder to solve). In above case we can make two points from one point e.g. point 1 became points: 1' and 1'' and the weight (connected to point 1) in the graph will change.

Are there well-known algorithms to solve TSP in case that if I visit city 1' I must visit city 1'' (and symmetrically)?

Comment: The tour will include both 1' and 1" in any case !?

Comment: Yes, we can assume that you must visit both points but you can start from 1' or 1''.

Comment: You missed my point. A tour always visits all points (and the starting point is immaterial).

Comment: More precise when you visit 1' the next point MUST be 1'', of course you can visit firstly 1'' and then 1'.

Comment: Please rephrase "(because in a case of choose another shapes the problem will be much harder to solve)". Unless your distances are asymmetrical, I think your problem can be reduced to a standard TSP in which you replace the distance from 1' and 1'' to other cities by the respective minimal distance. The distances between N' and N'' are a constant to the total length and do not change regardless of the order in which you travel through the cities.